# When/how to use nonlocal?

Tags: python, recursion

I'm having trouble understanding when to use nonlocal.

I was writing a recursive solution to a Leetcode problem (210 Course Schedule II) and I originally added a "nonlocal visited" as the first line within the dfs function. However, I removed it and it works fine. When do I need to be using nonlocal?

```
class Solution:
    def findOrder(self, numCourses: int, prerequisites: List[List[int]]) -> List[int]:
        res = []
        adjList = defaultdict(list)
        visited = set()

        # build adjacency matrix
        for prereq in prerequisites:
            adjList[prereq[0]].append(prereq[1])
            
        # define dfs algorithm
        def dfs(curr, path):
            if curr in visited:
                return True
            if curr in path:
                return False
            path.add(curr)
            for course in adjList[curr]:
                if not dfs(course, path):
                    return False
            path.remove(curr)
            visited.add(curr)
            res.append(curr)
            return True

        # topological sort
        for course in range(numCourses):
            if not dfs(course, set()):
                return []

        return res
```

Answer (score 0):

`nonlocal` is only needed if you want to assign to a name defined in an enclosing scope. `dfs` does not assign to the name `invalid`, it only *looks up* its value in order to invoke its `add` method. Since `visited` is not defined locally in `dfs`, the name lookup algorithm succeeds in finding it in the local scope of `findOrder`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a silly example of `nonlocal` usage:

```
def make_repeater(first_value):
    """Make function which returns argument from previous call"""

    remembered_value = first_value

    def repeater(next_value):
        nonlocal remembered_value
        rtn, remembered_value = remembered_value, next_value
        return rtn

    return repeater
```

Usage:

```
repeater = make_repeater(55)
repeater(10) # returns 55
repeater(88) # returns 10
repeater(20) # returns 88
```

Why is `nonlocal` needed here? Without it, `remembered_value` would be a local variable in `repeater` (because there is an assignment to it) and it would be uninitialised.

Why such a silly example? Because I can't think of a good one! There is actually rarely a good reason to use `nonlocal` (or `global` either). If you find yourself needing it, I would say you probably either have a case of bad design or you stumbled upon a very rare case where this is in fact useful.

Comment: Here's a possibly less contrived example: you have deeply nested dict/list data structure, say, a tree of comments, and you want to find the most upvoted one, or the total of all upvotes. You might write a recursive inner function that traverses the tree and reassigns to a `best` variable in the outer scope using `nonlocal`. In other words, you're keeping track of a single scalar value rather than a list. But you're right, generally you don't use `nonlocal` much. In spite of their similarities, `nonlocal` is generally a lot less of a code smell than `global`.

Comment: A simple, useful use of `nonlocal` might be to increment a counter on each call to the inner function. It's not thread-safe, and `counter = itertools.count()` in the closure scope, advancing it using `nextval = next(counter)` is the better way to implement such a design (and wouldn't require `nonlocal`), but for people who like building everything from scratch, I've seen that approach used.

Answer (score 0):

If your inner `dfs` function did this:

```
visited = <some value>
```

then that assignment would create a new variable `visited` that only existed inside that function (and any references to `visited` from that point on in the function would refer to the local variable). If instead you wanted it to be able to assign a new value to the `visited` in the outer scope, that's when you'd have to declare it `nonlocal`.

You're not doing that in the code as written; you're just using `visited`, not trying to reassign it. And even though some of the "using" does modify the contents of the variable, it doesn't change what the variable itself references.